# How to prevent same name XML tags being converted to Array when converting the XML String to JSON using Python?

Tags: python, json, xml, mongodb, parsing

I have an XML file which has the following format -

```
<root>
   <tag>
   This is the first Value.
   </tag>
   <tag>
   This is the second Value.
   </tag>
</root>
```

When I convert this XML string to JSON in Python using the following code

```
jsonString=json.dumps(XML_String)
```

The  tag becomes an array and the JSON file I get is like this -

```
{"root":["tag":"This is the first Value",
         "tag":"This is the second Value"]}
```

What I actually want is the `<root>` tag should be an object instead of an array. Like this -

```
{"root":{"tag":"This is the first Value",
         "tag":"This is the second Value"}}
```

How to achieve such kind of format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to generate is invalid JSON.

Well, perhaps not totally invalid, but at least contrary to good practice: RFC 8259 says: "When the names within an object are not unique, the behavior of software that receives such an object is unpredictable.  Many implementations report the last name/value pair only.  Other implementations report an error or fail to parse the object, and some implementations report all of the name/value pairs, including duplicates."

So don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by creating customized JSON string. And it actually worked. Arrays were not created.